# Why Am I getting an error? stating: Invalid attempt to destructure non-iterable instance in react native

Tags: javascript, react-native

I am getting a Invalid attempt to destructure non-iterable instance and I dont know what it means, I have sent an image below. [This is the expo app showing me the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ytytx.jpg) There are 3 javascript files that I have programmed to make render the app, App js is the file actually being rendered.

App.js

```
import React from 'react'
import WaterConsumption from './src/screens/WaterConsumption'

const App = () => {
  return <WaterConsumption />
}

export default App
```

WaterConsumption.js

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import { SafeAreaView, Text, StyleSheet, TextInput, Button } from 'react-native'
import Title from '../components/Title'

const WaterConsumption = () => {
  const [text, onChangeText] = useState('')
  const [amountOfWater, setAmountOfWater] = useState(null)
  const { container, info, textInput, amountOfWaterStyle } = styles

  const convertAmount = () => {
    try {
      var liters = text * 0.24
      setAmountOfWater(`${liters} liters`)
    } catch {
      setAmountOfWater('Try again! calculation not possible')
    }
  }

  return (
    <SafeAreaView style={container}>
      <Title titleText={"Water Consumption"} backgroundColor={"teal"} />
      <Text style={info}>
        Enter the number of glasses of water you consume in a day
      </Text>
      <TextInput
        style={textInput}
        value={text}
        onChangeText={onChangeText}
        placeholder="Enter value"
      />
      <Text style={amountOfWaterStyle}>{amountOfWater}</Text>
      <Button title="Liter" onPress={convertAmount} color="white" />
    </SafeAreaView>
  )
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: 'teal',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'space-around'
  },

  info: {
    fontSize: 20,
    textAlign: 'center',
    color: 'white'
  },

  textInput: {
    height: 40,
    width: 400,
    margin: 12,
    borderWidth: 1,
    padding: 10,
    backgroundColor: 'white',
    borderRadius: 10,
    opacity: 0.5
  },

  amountOfWaterStyle: {
    fontSize: 18,
    color: 'white'
  }
})

export default WaterConsumption
```

Title.js

```
import React from 'react'
import { Text, StyleSheet } from 'react-native'

const Title = (props) => {
  const [titleText, backgroundColor] = props

  return (
    <Text style={(styles.title, { backgroundColor: backgroundColor })}>
      {titleText}
    </Text>
  )
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  title: {
    fontSize: 35,
    paddingHorizontal: 25,
    paddingVertical: 5,
    alignSelf: 'center'
  }
})

export default Title
```

I am expecting no errors displayed and to see my title on screen with all of it's stylesheet attributes. I haven't tried much except changing the values in WaterConsumption where I placed curly braces around the prop parameters.

Comment: `[titleText, backgroundColor] = props` is your problem. `props` is an object, not an array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message "Invalid attempt to destructure non-iterable instance" is telling you that you're attempting to destructure something that isn't an array using array destructuring syntax. For example, consider the code

```js
const [foo, bar] = 12;
```

What is javascript supposed to do here? There isn't a first element to assign to `foo` or a second element to assign to `bar`, so it throws this error.

I think where this is coming from is this line in `Title.js`

```js
const [titleText, backgroundColor] = props
```

`props` is an object, so when you try to destructure it as an array, javascript gets all confused and throws an error. Instead, I believe this line should use curly braces, for object desctructuring

```js
const { titleText, backgroundColor } = props
```